# What can reduce physical symptoms of mental exhaustion, when you cannot remove the root cause?

Tags: nutrition, sleep, exercise, mental-exhaustion

If a person decides to work a mentally demanding job, giving their all to it, and makes themselves exhausted every day, what can they do to prevent/alleviate the feelings of exhaustion which plague them throughout the week and weekend?

I'm not asking about physically demanding jobs (e.g. manually digging holes all day) although the job in question rarely involves sitting down. I think it is mental overload manifesting itself as exhaustion. I'm talking about a job where you work an 8 or 9 hour shift without a break, no quiet moments, always maintaining high concentration.

I'm guessing the main solution might be *sleeping for as many hours as possible*, since that is what the body appears to be suggesting! But maybe there are other nutritional/medical/psychological tactics that can reduce the level of misery slightly? Or make the body more able to cope with this assault?

**I know the problem is a mental one, but what can be done to the human body to reduce the magnitude of the inevitable outcomes, or to return to 'normal' faster?**

Comment: Can you give some additional hint about what the job is about? Is it possible to decline certain request at the job?

Comment: The job: Teaching a class of 30 5-year olds. The crucial point: giving your all, 100% every second of the day, doing it all properly (if it were me, I'd take it easy at some point!). There is not one minute to have a calm thought all day, there's just a relentless barrage of incoming information or questions. The issue is constant mental processing, with no rest periods, even if seated. Once kids disappear there's a rush of paperwork and no let up in pace if all appropriate tasks are to be crammed into the day. Not everyone will work in this way, caring nothing for themself, but some do.

Comment: Honestly - hard to say,
i usually try to listen something good of the German music, such as [DanceCore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbnD5qfORB0)

[TechnoBase](https://www.technobase.fm/) | [RauteMusik](http://www.rautemusik.fm/club/) | [Sunshine-Live](http://www.sunshine-live.de/)